# Invalid input: domain clientuserinfo is not present

Tags: google-admin-sdk

As per the google documentation we ended up creating a service account (since there’s no user intervention and it’s middleware invoking the google api) and associating with the google admin api; We’re able to get a token back which we’re sending to the google api but here’s the response we’re seeing:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer  /devices/chromeos?access_token=y000000000898999(mock token digits)

Response: {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
             {
        "domain": "global",
         "reason": "invalid",
         "message": "Invalid Input: Domain ClientUserInfo is not present"
      }
     ],
     "code": 400,
       "message": "Invalid Input: Domain ClientUserInfo is not present"
    }
 }
```

Any ideas? My thought is that it’s to do with the my_customer as the id.

Answer (score 1):

Using `my_customer` as the id should work but in this case, since the service account is not related to a domain, you are getting the error.

Admin SDK should be access by the admin of the domain. So in this case if you are using a service account, you should [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) the domain admin account in order to make a valid call on his behalf.

You can also try this method from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/list), accessing it as the admin of the domain.